# How to combine a noisy (but unbiased) estimate with a precise (but possibly biased) estimate in A/B tests?

Tags: mse, bias-variance-tradeoff, optimal

Suppose I want to estimate some set of unknown quantities $\theta_1$, …, $\theta_N$. For each $i \in \{1, …, N\}$, I have two estimators: $\hat{\theta_i}_A$ and $ \hat{\theta_i}_B$. The goal is to combine these estimators to form an "optimal" estimator, where there is some discretion in defining what "optimality" mean. Ultimately, we need to tradeoff bias and variance.

We don't know the distributions of $\hat{\theta_i}_A$ and $\hat{\theta_i}_B$. However, we know that the means and variances take the following forms (true for all i):

$$E(\hat{\theta_i}_A) = \theta_i$$
$$V(\hat{\theta_i}_A) = \sigma_A^2$$
$$E(\hat{\theta_i}_B) = \theta_i + \beta$$
$$V(\hat{\theta_i}_B) = \sigma_B^2$$

$\sigma_B^2 < \sigma_A^2$. The variances are known. $\beta$ is unknown. N is not very large — let’s say N is between 15 and 35. In other words, $\hat{\theta_i}_A$ is unbiased and but has variance that is meaningfully greater than $\hat{\theta_i}_B$. We don't know whether $\hat{\theta_i}_B$ is biased ($\beta$ is probably close to 0).

Stakeholders have a strong desire to avoid estimates that are “too biased,” although they can’t formulate that worry precisely. Current practice is to just use  $\hat{\theta_i}_A$, but there is a general desire to take advantage of $\hat{\theta_i}_B$ to reduce the uncertainty in the estimates.

What are some candidates for the “best” way to combine $\hat{\theta_i}_A$ and $\hat{\theta_i}_B$ to get a final estimate for each $\theta_i$? Feel free to supply your own definition of “best” or to supply assumptions that you feel are missing. I am looking to survey a variety of reasonable solutions.

One way would be to choose a weighted average $$ \hat{\theta_i} = p \hat{\theta_i}_A + (1-p) \hat{\theta_i}_B $$ to minimize MSE -- we'd have to estimate the MSE for $\hat{\theta_i}_B$ to do this.

A second version of the the problem is to assume multiplicative instead of additive bias for $ \hat{\theta_i}_B $ — in practice we don’t know whether the bias is additive or multiplicative. I’d be interested in comments on this variation, as well.

Here's an example where this could arise: you have a retail website that sells shoes. You want to test N different variations of the website to see whether the variations increase the number of purchases that occur in a week. You can run A/B tests to test the variations. You can compare actual purchases in each experiment arm, but purchases are rare and estimates will be noisy. You have an ML model that predicts purchases, so you could also compare predicted purchases. This will be much less noisy, but the ML model could be biased and stakeholders are afraid to rely on an evaluation based on modeled (rather than actual) outcomes.

Comment: Consider estimating the population variance from a sample drawn from a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance.  The usual unbiased estimator is $\frac1{n-1} \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ while the maximum likelihood estimator is the slightly biased $\frac1{n} \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ and this has lower variance.  If you set your optimality criterion to minimise expected mean square error (so the sum of  variance and the square of the bias), then you would use $\frac1{n+1} \sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ and I do not see how this can reasonably be described as a combination of the previous two estimators

Answer (score 1):

A weighted mean would of course always be biased by $(1-p) \beta$. I guess, the variance bias trade-off could of course be positive.

If you really had the exact assumptions above, you can of course do much better than that. If you really believed that there is always a fixed bias $\beta$ for the second estimator, then I'd think you could do a pretty good job by writing down this exact model and estimating the parameters. Given the small sample size, you could elicit (from experts) what the various model parameters could roughly be to at least have weakly informative (or even fully informative) priors in a Bayesian setting. That's a really nice approach, by the way, if you want to investigate different notions of optimality, because you can pick estimates based on MCMC samples so as to minimize some loss function you may care about.

One thing you didn't say and which you'd have to make choices about is whether the errors in predictions of the two approaches are correlated.

In practice, you'd of course rarely be sure that the particular model form you wrote down would apply (e.g. both methods might be a bit biased, variability may also depend on circumstances and not be exactly known, the size of bias might change depending on each case etc.).